# How to change the class of a <li> element after clicking on a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to modify the class of certain elements of my sidebar when some user clicks on a tab. In short, change the class of the sidebar elements to `current class + " active"`

I have implemented a partially working solution as I could after doing some research on my own.

This part of the code is key:

```
$(".setActive").click(function() {
            $(".sidebar-item:contains('"+$(this).attr("data-target")+"')").parent().parent().addClass(' active');
})
```

Actually, with that line of code, I change the class to `active` but there is a problem:

- I don't know how to remove the `active` class from the previously visited sidebar elements, then I am getting something like this:

[image: current result]

How can I solve this issue?

[JS FIDDLE LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/105/)

Comment: What I usually do is, first remove all `active` classes, then add `active` to the clicked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `active` class added before adding the current one

```
$(".setActive").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-element.active").removeClass('active');
    $(".sidebar-item:contains('"+$(this).attr("data-target")+"')").parent().parent().addClass(' active');
})
```

Comment: That worked like a charm